# How to modify error message in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup

I want to change one error message. After not typing a password the error message says:

> The password you entered is not correct. Please try again.

I want to use my own custom message and include clickable hyperlink in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A custom message text is easy. Set `IncorrectPassword` message in the [`[Messages]` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=messagessection):

```
[Messages]
IncorrectPassword=That is not the correct password, dude.
```

---

A custom message dialog with a clickable hyperlink is a *lot* more work. You would have to implement the validation on your own, creating the dialog programmatically.

Easier would be to add your hyperlink directly to the wizard password page.