# Handling and customizing errors and messages in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

Inno Setup will show different message boxes to the user.
For example,

1. When it tries to install a file that is in use, it will show a message to abort/ignore/cancel.
2. When the setup is installing the files and the target path will have low space while installing, the setup will give an error.

I need to customize these message boxes on my own. (I do not want these native messages to be shown to the user) for example, I need to show another message box, or even totally do not show a specific message from Inno Setup, or changing a label when that message is going to fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Inno Setup messages can be customized using the [`[Messages]` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=messagessection).

Some examples:

- [How to modify error message in Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57771954/850848)
- [Show a custom message for unsupported architectures](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42305206/850848)
- [How can I show my own message and then exit setup if the current version of Windows is not supported?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60867566/850848)

---

As for the change of the message box layout/design. You cannot really change it. With some fancy implementation of [`Check`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptcheck) and [`BeforeInstall` parameters](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptinstall), you might be able to catch *some* problems before Inno Setup detects them and handle them your custom way. But that's lot of work with unreliable results.

*If you tell us what are you trying to achieve more specifically, you may get more specific answer.*

---

If you need a solution that allows everything that Inno Setup allows on error, including clean abort of the installation, `Check` or `BeforeInstall` won't help as they do not have a way to cleanly abort it.

You would have to do all the checks before the installation, e.g. in [`CurStepChanged(ssInstall)`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurStepChanged).

```pascal
[Files]
Source: "MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Check: ShouldInstallFile

[Code]

var
  DontInstallFile: Boolean;

function ShouldInstallFile: Boolean;
begin
  Result := not DontInstallFile;
end;

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  FileName: string;
  Msg: string;
  Response: Integer;
begin
  if CurStep = ssInstall then
  begin
    FileName := ExpandConstant('{app}\MyProg.exe');
    repeat
      if FileExists(FileName) and (not DeleteFile(FileName)) then
      begin
        Msg := Format('File %s cannot be replaced', [FileName]);
        Response := MsgBox(Msg, mbError, MB_ABORTRETRYIGNORE)
        case Response of
          IDABORT: Abort;
          IDIGNORE: DontInstallFile := True;
        end;
      end;
    until (Response <> IDRETRY);
  end;
end;
```