# Rename and Change language `at least X MB of free disk space is required` page of Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

Rename and Change language  `a last 5.8 mb of free disk space is required` on Select Destination Location page of Inno Setup

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See [Handling and customizing errors and messages in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65980371/850848).

This particular message is defined by the `DiskSpaceGBLabel` and `DiskSpaceMBLabel`.

You can change it in the [`[Messages]` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=messagessection):

```
[Messages]
DiskSpaceGBLabel=At least [gb] GB of free disk space is required.
DiskSpaceMBLabel=At least [mb] MB of free disk space is required.
```