# Changing restart message on Inno Setup Prepare To Install page

Tags: inno-setup

I am building an installer in Inno Setup v6.2.1 with prerequisites, which include .NET, runtimes, and KB fixes (Windows 7 SP1). The goal is to do potentially several reboots depending on if the machine is missing KBs or .NET etc.

I am able to achieve what I want so far using `PrepareToInstall` and can change the text by returning the appropriate string.  No problems... however I can't find a way of changing the.

> Setup must restart your computer. After restarting your computer, run Setup again to complete the installation of xxxxx

Because I am creating a `runonce` entry, the installer will automatically run after reboot (which it does).  The text *"run Setup again"* is not relevant in my situation and I want to change the text to say that the installer will continue once you restart.

I have tried to find where to change this text but with no success.  I assume that `PreparingMemo` might be the candidate but no luck or not sure how to use it.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Handling and customizing errors and messages in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65980371/850848).

This particular message is defined by the `PrepareToInstallNeedsRestart` message.

You can change it in the [`[Messages]` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=messagessection):

```
[Messages]
PrepareToInstallNeedsRestart=Setup must restart your computer. After restarting your computer, the Setup will continue to complete the installation of [name].%n%nWould you like to restart now?
```

---

If you need to change the message text dynamically, assign `WizardForm.PreparingLabel.Caption`. E.g. from [`CurPageChanged(wpPreparing)` event](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurPageChanged).